# On stability of coherent sheaves over a quasiprojective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $n$ and $L$ be an ample line bundle on $X$. For any coherent sheaf $E$, one can define the first Chern class $C_1(E)$ and degree of $E$ to be $C_1(E)\cdot C_1(L)^{n-1}$. Then $E$ is called stable (Mumford-Takemoto) if for any coherent sub sheaf $F<E$ we have $\frac{deg F}{rank F}<\frac{deg E}{rank E}$.

Does this definition of a stable sheaf also hold for a smooth quasi projective variety? Where are we using the properness of the variety?

Comment: Probably that degree of 0-cycles is only defined for proper things

Comment: If we replace $c_1(L)^{n-1}$ with the class of a proper curve in $X$, the definition still at least formally makes sense. I guess this will be closely related to stability of $j_* E$ with $j$ the open immersion into a compactification (with complement of codimension $2$).